# Regex repeated replace

Tags: .net, regex

Is it possible to have a single but recurring regex.replace call?
e.g.

```
string dateText = "01\.02\\.2008";
string dateSeperators = @"\.|/|\\|-";
string result = Regex.Replace(dateText, dateSeperators, "."); // needs to be fixed. single call possible?
```

The result should give "01.02.2008".
Currrently i need 2 runs, first run the above replace then replace multiple occurence of dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use

```
string dateSeparators = @"(\.|/|\\|-)+";
```

to catch multiple separators in one go.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx) for details on regex quantifiers (like that "+").

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for your dateSeperators:

```
string dateSeperators = @"(\.|/|\\|-)+"
```

This yields:

```
01.02.2008
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateSeperators = @"(\.|/|\\|-)+";
```

That will match all repeating seperators.

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateSeparators = @"[./\\-]+";
```